# How do I combine two vba codes? Multiple list with item removal and a shown as other value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to combine two different vba code functions.

1. Create a multiple list with item removal
2. Show selected item as another predefined value

I have a vba code for both options, see below.

The first one does exactly what I want in terms of adding items to a list and removing an item if you click on it for a second time (so only unique values). This is important because the list is going to be long and when you click on the wrong one, you don't want to start over.

The second one does also create a multiple list and shows the corresponding shorter values. But this one doesn't have the functionality of removing an item. The long values need to be shown as shorter values, because of the long list. And the drop-down list should be the long version, so people don't need to learn the abbreviations by hard and I can still see what is needed.

Both vba codes are written by other people and not me. I just googled them, and I do understand a little bit of vba, but not enough to combine these two or rewrite a new one that can do both.

Is it possible to have both these functionalities and if so, how?

Extra but not a big problem:
If I add new values to the list to select from or change an abbreviation the values that were already selected in the drop-down list do not update. Is it possible to also add this inside the code?

I tried to combine them, but I failed. One vba code is written with destination range and the other with target range, so I think that is one of the reasons it is not working together. But I'm also not skilled enough.

First one:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String
DelimiterType = " | "
Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
Dim TargetType As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
 
Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
 
TargetType = 0
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or InStr(1, oldValue, " " & newValue & DelimiterType) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
 
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
End Sub
```

Second one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oldValue As String
    Dim newValue As String
    Dim selectedNum As Variant
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                     
            
            newValue = Target.Value
            selectedNum = Application.VLookup(newValue, Worksheets("PPE").Range("ShowAs"), 2, False)
            newValue = selectedNum
            Application.Undo
            oldValue = Target.Value
            If oldValue = "" Then
                Target.Value = newValue
            Else
                If InStr(1, oldValue, newValue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = oldValue & ", " & newValue
                Else:
                    Target.Value = oldValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm still trying to figure out how I can add my excel files to make it more clear.

Comment: Miss to attach the snippets of your code. Without them it is hardly to say anything.

Comment: OP has edited the post while you were trying to edit the post @Blackcat refresh ;)

Comment: @Notus i refreshed but cannot see.

Comment: Community bot approved your edit for whatever reason and then Mayukh edited on top of it. I have no idea why your edit got approved but I'll rectify the deletion of the code.

Comment: @OP: Would there be any conflicting issues with both codes? If not, try putting everything between `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)` and `End Sub` to a new Sub, i.e. `Sub firstChange(ByVal Destination As Range)`, the same for the other one but with `Target` instead of `Destination` and then in a standard `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) -- firstChange(Target) -- secondChange(Target)`. That way, it calls both and your logic remains as is.

Comment: @Notus_Panda If I put the two codes one after the other it gives an error I think because the names are the same. So I changed that and then the code does run, but doesn't execute the second code (no abbriviations are made).
I'm not sure if I understand your second option, but I will try it now :)

Comment: @Notus_Panda I tried what you said (but not sure if I did it right), but it gives an Run-time error '424': Object required. When clicking on Debug it highlights "firstChange(Target)" in the last part of the code.

Comment: What does your -- mean before the firstChange(Target) and secondChange(Target)? Maybe that's where I go wrong. I did this:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

    `firstChange (Target)`
    `secondChange (Target)`

`End Sub`

Comment: I keep switching around the need for brackets in my head, posted an answer to clarify what I meant @Pauline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thank you both for your time! Even chat gpt 3,5 couldn't get as far as you, but I could use the 4th version from someone. And after 20 minutes of discussing with chat gpt and a lot of fails it finally found a code that does exactly what I want :) Even though I'm still curious how yours work.

I now have a multiple list that after selecting a value/string from the list it only shows me the abbreviations I created and when I selected the wrong value I can click on it again in the multiple list and then it disappears. The cells are also protected from invalid input.

For other people with the same question, this code did the trick for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim arr
    Dim abbreviation As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal

    ' Controleer of de nieuwe waarde een geldige selectie is
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(newVal, Worksheets("PPE").Range("List"), 0)) Then
        abbreviation = GetAbbreviation(newVal)
    Else
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    If Target.Column = 2 And InStr(Target.Validation.Formula1, "List") > 0 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
            ' Eerste selectie
            Target.Value = abbreviation
        Else
            arr = Split(oldVal, "|")
            If IsInArray(abbreviation, arr) Then
                ' Item verwijderen
                Target.Value = JoinArrayWithout(arr, abbreviation)
            Else
                ' Item toevoegen
                Target.Value = Trim(oldVal & " | " & abbreviation)
            End If
        End If
    End If

CleanUp:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function GetAbbreviation(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPE")
    For Each cell In ws.Range("ShowAs")
        If cell.Value = value Then
            GetAbbreviation = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    GetAbbreviation = value
End Function

Function IsInArray(ByVal value As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Trim(arr(i)) = Trim(value) Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False
End Function

Function JoinArrayWithout(arr As Variant, ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Trim(arr(i)) <> Trim(value) Then
            result = result & arr(i) & "|"
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(result) > 0 Then
        JoinArrayWithout = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    Else
        JoinArrayWithout = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Maybe one day if I have recovered from this I will try to find out how the already selected values from the multiple lists in a cell can be updated automatically after I changed an abbreviation or when I add new values to the list with available values. And put the selected values/abbreviations in alphabetical order (this shouldn't be that hard I think). Maybe I need an vba code training...

Thanks again!

Comment: To update when you update an abbreviation, you could do something similar, with the Change event on that EPP sheet and then for every cell in the other sheet that has the validation lists check if the previous abbreviation was in it, and if so, change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround of calling the two subs one after the other

Rename the second sub to e.g. testsub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

'here is your code

testsub target

End Sub


Private Sub testsub(ByVal target As Range)

Debug.Print "called from worksheet change"; target.Address

'here is the second code

End Sub
```

Comment: From where to where should I put my codes in here?

Comment: Both from the first till the last line the codes without the Sub and End Sub statements. Rename is only because there cannot be two change event sub on one sheet. And can comment out the Debug.Print line it is for testing purposes.

Comment: I get the same issue as with the solution of @Notus_Panda. The code doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't execute them. I simply have cells with the data validation list.

Comment: Did you get the message in the immediate window?

Comment: You will not get error messages because there is an On Error Goto statement in the code.  Comment it out to check for errors in the shorter sub, and for the second check in the longer one too.

Comment: I think I found the problem of not executing the first code. I changed target to Destination in the first line `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)`. But then it set that `testsub target` was a variable not defined. So I changed that target also to Destination (which I don't know if that makes sense since the testsub is with Target. But it does run without error, only the first code is executed (so it makes a multiple list including removing items). Only the second code to create abbreviations isn't doing anything.

Comment: What is the target address printed in the immediate window?

Comment: E.g. there is no cell validation in the target cell. With debugging the second sub can get more exact clues.

Comment: When writing the code like you suggested with `Debug.Print` it doesn't show me an immediate window. It also doesn't give an error when adding something from the drop-down list. It also isn't an multiple list anymore, but just the simple data validation list.

Comment: View->Immediate Window or CTRL+G

Comment: Ah found it. If I use your code with `target` at the first code it is giving an Run-time error '424': Object required as soon as the first Destination is called `If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`. So I changed the Private Sub again to Destination instead of target. Then it gives the same error but then on the `testsub target`. So I changed that target also in Destination and then the code runs without giving an error. But the second code to make abbreviations isn't doing anything. 
The Immediate window gives 'called from worksheet change$O$14' (or any other cellnumber I adjust the list)

Comment: OK. Second sub require that the change is in column B and the changed cell has a cell validation.

Comment: Yes, I know because it says `If target.Column = 2 Then`. But in my own file that number is 15 so column O. The code I provided here is for a test file wanted to upload on this website, but I still don't know how to do that. Also `Worksheet("PPE").Range("ShowAs")`  is different in my file: `Worksheet("PBM").Range("Dropdown")`, but that shouldn't cause the error I think as long as my code refers to the right sheets and lists. My cells in column O do have a data validation list.

Comment: Then change value 2 to 15. And there has to be a name in Name Manager as "Dropdown"

Comment: Yes I both have that since the beginning. So that can't be the issue unfortunately. I showed you the outcome of my own file instead of the testing file I created for this website, but it gives the same problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is very simplistic and only meant as an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstChange(ByVal Destination As Range)
    If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Destination.Offset(, 1).Value = "Yes"
End Sub

Sub secChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "Nice"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    firstChange Target
    secChange Target
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I made a mistake with stating firstChange(Target) at firsthand, sorry for the mislead.

Your logic from "First One" and "Second One" go in firstChange and secChange so you won't have to change anything of the code itself.

Comment: I changed the last part of the code, but now it doesn't perform any of the two codes. My cells are now just normal data validation lists. Is it possible it has something to do with the `Application.EnableEvents` that are also in my two sub codes?

Comment: Put a stopmark at `firstChange Target` and then step through your code with F8 and see what's going on/wrong. (you'll need to trigger the event by changing something)

Comment: Like I need to create a macro and run it line after line?

Comment: Checkout [this link](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) on how to debug. Set the breakpoint, as shown from the link, in your code at `firstChange Target` in the Change Event and then step through the code once you change something in your sheet.

Comment: I messed something up, so I added your suggested code again. It does execute the first code so I do get a multiple list, just not the abbreviations. So the second code seems like it doesn't do anything. But no errors, so I don't see how I can debug it. Also after shutting off the `firstChange Target` by making it a comment it doesn't give an error, but it stops making a multiple list which makes sense by shutting it off.

Comment: Comment out `On Error GoTo Exitsub` as well and then see where the issue is at, if you use F8 you should be able to see what the code is doing step by step. Since you're not dealing with a loop, this should be fairly easy to see where the issue is.

Comment: I don't know why but after closing the document and reopening it I didn't get an error and the first code executed fine so I did get an multiple list. That's when I tried blocking `firstChange Target` as you suggested before and it finally did something logical. It didn't execute the first code (obviously) and it did execute the second code! So it seems like they both work fine, but still not together. I'm now going to try your newest suggestion.

Comment: If I have your original code and only comment out the `On Error GoTo Exitsub` in the second code it indeed gives an error, on `Application.Undo. "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Undo' of object'_Application' failed. I can't do anything at all at this point with the F8 button, because it keeps giving the error and jumping to that line.

Comment: I have successfully run your code without getting the error you have. Could you share how the ShowAs range looks like and how you filled the Datavalidation range?

Comment: That gives me hope :)
Data Validation settings:
Allow: List
Source: =List        (I made a "list" with Name Manager, =PPE!$A$2:$A$5)

Range of ShowAs (also a "list" created with Name Manager): =PPE!$A$2:$B$5